# how to prevent message creation api to resend complete message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I use graph api to create a message with attachment(s).

All runs fine but the server send back the complete message in response, including the attachments.

Is there a way to only get the message id in the response ?

I try with :

```
string webApiUrl = $"{_apiUrl}v1.0/users/{senderId}/messages?$select=id"
```

but I still get the whole message with 98ko of attachment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the prefer:return=minimal header in the request which will mean you will just get a 204 response. However the id of the item that was created will be returned in the location header (the response should really have the OData-EntityId if they are following the oData spec to the letter, also I'm not sure why it return the Outlook v2 location rather then the graph but the message Id is the same between them)

[image]

Comment: you are correct, no odata, but a location. in my case in the form: 
Location:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('someId@someDomain.tld')/messages('AAkALgAAAAAAHYQDEEc2byACqAC-EWg0AXgMvIPCQGGB-yp_lefwABFOnBdAAA')